# React-Table Sort with Pagination Unexpected Results

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-table

Getting some unexpected results while using react-table. I've combined examples for pagination-controlled and sorting from [react-table examples](https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-table/tree/master/examples). The issue i'm experiencing is the table hooks seem to be resetting the page index back to default on a second re-render. This is resulting in fetchData being called twice when paging back and forth. Below is a reproduction of the problem i'm facing:

```
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import { useTable, usePagination, useSortBy } from "react-table";

import makeData from "./makeData";

const Styles = styled.div`
  `

// Let's add a fetchData method to our Table component that will be used to fetch
// new data when pagination state changes
// We can also add a loading state to let our table know it's loading new data
function Table({
  columns,
  data,
  fetchData,
  loading,
  pageCount: controlledPageCount
}) {
  const {
    getTableProps,
    getTableBodyProps,
    headerGroups,
    prepareRow,
    page,
    canPreviousPage,
    canNextPage,
    pageOptions,
    pageCount,
    gotoPage,
    nextPage,
    previousPage,
    setPageSize,
    // Get the state from the instance
    state: { pageIndex, pageSize }
  } = useTable(
    {
      columns,
      data,
      initialState: { pageIndex: 0 }, // Pass our hoisted table state
      manualPagination: true, // Tell the usePagination
      // hook that we'll handle our own data fetching
      // This means we'll also have to provide our own
      // pageCount.
      pageCount: controlledPageCount
    },
    useSortBy,
    usePagination
  );

  // Listen for changes in pagination and use the state to fetch our new data
  React.useEffect(() => {
    fetchData({ pageIndex, pageSize });
  }, [fetchData, pageIndex, pageSize]);

  // Render the UI for your table
  return (
    <>
      <pre>
        <code>
          {JSON.stringify(
            {
              pageIndex,
              pageSize,
              pageCount,
              canNextPage,
              canPreviousPage
            },
            null,
            2
          )}
        </code>
      </pre>
      <table {...getTableProps()}>
        <thead>
          {headerGroups.map(headerGroup => (
            <tr {...headerGroup.getHeaderGroupProps()}>
              {headerGroup.headers.map(column => (
                <th {...column.getHeaderProps(column.getSortByToggleProps())}>
                  {column.render("Header")}
                  <span>
                    {column.isSorted
                      ? column.isSortedDesc
                        ? " "
                        : " "
                      : ""}
                  </span>
                </th>
              ))}
            </tr>
          ))}
        </thead>
        <tbody {...getTableBodyProps()}>
          {page.map((row, i) => {
            prepareRow(row);
            return (
              <tr {...row.getRowProps()}>
                {row.cells.map(cell => {
                  return (
                    <td {...cell.getCellProps()}>{cell.render("Cell")}</td>
                  );
                })}
              </tr>
            );
          })}
          <tr>
            {loading ? (
              // Use our custom loading state to show a loading indicator
              <td colSpan="10000">Loading...</td>
            ) : (
              <td colSpan="10000">
                Showing {page.length} of ~{controlledPageCount * pageSize}{" "}
                results
              </td>
            )}
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      {/* 
        Pagination can be built however you'd like. 
        This is just a very basic UI implementation:
      */}
      <div className="pagination">
        <button onClick={() => gotoPage(0)} disabled={!canPreviousPage}>
          {"<<"}
        </button>{" "}
        <button onClick={() => previousPage()} disabled={!canPreviousPage}>
          {"<"}
        </button>{" "}
        <button onClick={() => nextPage()} disabled={!canNextPage}>
          {">"}
        </button>{" "}
        <button onClick={() => gotoPage(pageCount - 1)} disabled={!canNextPage}>
          {">>"}
        </button>{" "}
        <span>
          Page{" "}
          <strong>
            {pageIndex + 1} of {pageOptions.length}
          </strong>{" "}
        </span>
        <span>
          | Go to page:{" "}
          <input
            type="number"
            defaultValue={pageIndex + 1}
            onChange={e => {
              const page = e.target.value ? Number(e.target.value) - 1 : 0;
              gotoPage(page);
            }}
            style={{ width: "100px" }}
          />
        </span>{" "}
        <select
          value={pageSize}
          onChange={e => {
            setPageSize(Number(e.target.value));
          }}
        >
          {[10, 20, 30, 40, 50].map(pageSize => (
            <option key={pageSize} value={pageSize}>
              Show {pageSize}
            </option>
          ))}
        </select>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

// Let's simulate a large dataset on the server (outside of our component)
const serverData = makeData(10000);

function App() {
  const columns = React.useMemo(
    () => [
      {
        Header: "Name",
        columns: [
          {
            Header: "First Name",
            accessor: "firstName"
          },
          {
            Header: "Last Name",
            accessor: "lastName"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        Header: "Info",
        columns: [
          {
            Header: "Age",
            accessor: "age"
          },
          {
            Header: "Visits",
            accessor: "visits"
          },
          {
            Header: "Status",
            accessor: "status"
          },
          {
            Header: "Profile Progress",
            accessor: "progress"
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    []
  );

  // We'll start our table without any data
  const [data, setData] = React.useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = React.useState(false);
  const [pageCount, setPageCount] = React.useState(0);
  const fetchIdRef = React.useRef(0);

  const fetchData = React.useCallback(({ pageSize, pageIndex }) => {
    // This will get called when the table needs new data
    // You could fetch your data from literally anywhere,
    // even a server. But for this example, we'll just fake it.

    // Give this fetch an ID
    const fetchId = ++fetchIdRef.current;

    // Set the loading state
    setLoading(true);

    // We'll even set a delay to simulate a server here
    setTimeout(() => {
      // Only update the data if this is the latest fetch
      if (fetchId === fetchIdRef.current) {
        const startRow = pageSize * pageIndex;
        const endRow = startRow + pageSize;
        setData(serverData.slice(startRow, endRow));

        // Your server could send back total page count.
        // For now we'll just fake it, too
        setPageCount(Math.ceil(serverData.length / pageSize));

        setLoading(false);
      }
    }, 1000);
  }, []);

  return (
    <Styles>
      <Table
        columns={columns}
        data={data}
        fetchData={fetchData}
        loading={loading}
        pageCount={pageCount}
      />
    </Styles>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Here is a codesandbox to observe the behaivor: [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/lively-paper-1nc6p?file=/src/App.js:0-6884)

Also worth noting that the issue does not occur after removing the useSort hook along with call to column.getSortByToggleProps().

Comment: Came across the same problem, here is a detailed discussion on this topic: https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-table/issues/411

Answer (score 11):

By mutating `data` with every `fetchPage` request, you signal to something in react-table that "hey, our data refreshed! It must be new data! Reset the page!"

[The usePagination docs](https://react-table-v7.tanstack.com/docs/api/usePagination#usepagination) mention an `autoResetPage` property -- setting it `false` enables the expected behavior. Note that it also disables page-resetting on sort, filter, and grouping, so additional logic may be required if you plan on using those as well.

Comment: Thanks mate you save my time

Comment: This is the correct answer. You can also read here for more info https://react-table.tanstack.com/docs/faq#how-do-i-stop-my-table-state-from-automatically-resetting-when-my-data-changes

Answer (score 0):

I think in react-table (v7.7.0), you can avoid unexpected results in pagination by adding `autoResetPage: false` to `useTable` hook, (and also avoid unexpected results in filtering and sorting  by adding `autoResetFilters: false`, and `autoResetSortBy: false` to `useTable` hook) like so:

```js
const tableInstance = useTable({
        columns,
        data,
        autoResetPage: false,
        autoResetFilters: false,
        autoResetSortBy: false
    }, usePagination)
```

You can also add `autoResetAll: false` instead of those three lines of code.